# Github command line vs. Xcode vs. Git app for using github?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, github, version-control

I am a new developer who has started by learning Swift with XCode. I am taking an online course with Udacity, which provides detailed and high quality instruction on how to do version control with Github using the command line. In a one-on-one session with a mentor, however, she was using XCode's built-in git management tools for branches, commits, etc.

Since XCode itself can manage git version control, I can use the command line and I can also use the Git desktop app, my question is: what will be the expectation of future employers as to what tool I use or do they care?

I recognize this is a somewhat subjective question, so I have tried to limit its scope by not asking what your *preferred* method is, but rather, to what degree there is uniformity amongst potential employers' expectations.

Thanks.

Comment: The employers don't care on what tool you use as long as you are clear with git concepts especially related to push, merge and branching. So you are free to use whichever you are comfortable with.

Comment: Just a personal choice some people would like command line some will xcode's inbuilt ones and some will like something else

Comment: The expectation by employers is that you understand the concepts. A lot of iOS engineers I've been running into lately use Source Tree. Different GUIs provide varying levels of functionality while the command line can do everything.

Comment: Also, GitHub != git, your potential employer is just as likely to use BitBucket or Gitlab, or even have a private git server setup with no web interface. git servers in their simplest form are really just ssh servers with git installed on them.

Comment: And though git is basically the default, don't forget about mercurial and SVN, which I've had a least one engineer tell me he's still using at work.

Answer (score 1):

**It depends on which projects the employers will develop and which SDK they are plan to use.** Such as for developing mac app in xcode, you can directly use the IDE of git in VCS (version control system), for developing a windows app by visual studio, you can use the team explorer to manage your git repo etc.

If you are learning for git now, I will suggest you study git with git command line by referring [git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2), reasons as below:

- Other tools about git are all based on git commands.
- After you familiar with git commands, it’s easy to use git options on other tools.
- git commands including all the functions, while other tools may not have the functions: checkout to a history commit, reset to a previous version, rewrite history by `git filter-branch` etc.